# Am I getting a proper WiFi signal dBm reading?

Tags: c#, wifi

This function below gets the WiFi signal from the system. It is currently displaying a "0" on my form (indicating a strong connection I assume). The machine that I am running this on a workplace HP that is on the company network. It doesn't seem to have an external WiFi button or such. Is the "0" I am getting a true value or do I need to test this on a true wireless device?

```
public static int GetSignalStrengthAsInt()
{
    Int32 returnStrength = 0;
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = null;
    try
    {
        searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher( 
            @"root\WMI", 
            @"select Ndis80211ReceivedSignalStrength 
              from MSNdis_80211_ReceivedSignalStrength 
              where active=true");

        // Call the get in order to populate the collection
        ManagementObjectCollection adapterObjects = searcher.Get();

        // Loop though the management object and pull out the signal strength
        foreach ( ManagementObject mo in adapterObjects )
        {
            returnStrength = Convert.ToInt32( 
                mo["Ndis80211ReceivedSignalStrength"].ToString());
            break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        if ( searcher != null )
        {
            searcher.Dispose();
        }
    }
    return returnStrength;            
}
```

the returnStrength is being displayed on a text box at the moment.

Comment: Check http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2007/03/22/how-can-i-determine-the-signal-strength-of-a-wireless-connection.aspx I think it covers your question

Answer (score 0):

First, please note that I do not know your development environment. The following are general indications based on experience:

- The signal strength is usually given either in dB units or in dBm
  units.
- dB is used for signal/noise ratio. A reasonably good signal is at
  least 18~20 dB.
- dBm is used for the pure power received. It is normally in the range 
  -20dBm (excellent) to -80dBm (very poor)

0 is often seen when the information cannot be obtained from the device. So my guess is that your value is invalid.